# How to run R.exe without args in WPF

Tags: c#

I create a process to run 'cmd.exe' and redirect the stdout,stderr,stdin.
It seems work good. But when I input 'R' and try to run 'R.exe', it doesn't work and show the message below.

> Fatal error: you must specify '--save','--no-save' or '--vanilla'

```
 Process _process = new Process();
 ProcessStartInfo _startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
 _startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
 _startInfo.Arguments = "";
 _startInfo.RedirectStandartInput = true;
 _startInfo.RedirectStandartOutput = true;
 _startInfo.RedirectStandartError = true;
 _startInfo.CreateNoWindows = true;
```

I expect that the process which is runing 'cmd.exe' can run R.exe after inputting 'R' without another args.

**Current Output**

[image]

**Expected Output**

[image]

Comment: Could you try `where R`, see if its the same executable in both cases?

Comment: From both images, I don't think you are running the same file? Try including the full path to the executable i.e `C:\Users\user\R.exe`.

Comment: I have try to input the full path to the executable. It show the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I have try to input the full path to the executable. It show the same result.
But if the ProcessStartInfo is changed, it does work as I expect.

```
_startInfo.CreateNoWindows = false;
```

And I find an interesting appearance.

When CMD is running in system process, I try to redirect the output of R.exe and input "R > D:\a.txt". And the fatal error message will be alse shown.